# postfix someone is trying to access my server, failing auth access. How to ban it?

Tags: postfix, email, email-server

I have a postfix mail server.

I'm currently receiving a lot of messages telling me that someone with certain IP address is trying to access my server, failing always in the AUTH LOGIN

So... I'm kind of tired of receiving this messages. How can I block this IP address from trying  to access my server?

I already tried this (and maybe I tried it badly, please correct me if I'm wrong...):

1)

In main.cf

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/ip_access
```

And in ip_access file

```
ip.address.num.ber REJECT
```

and after that, run

```
postmap ip_access
```

And restarting the server, it really doesn't works. I still receive annoying messages...

I receive nothing at logs

2)

In main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/ip_access, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/ip_access
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/ip_access, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/ip_access
```

In ip_access file

```
ip.address.num.ber 550 we do not accept spam
```

and after that, run again

```
postmap ip_access
```

And restarting the server, I get this at logs:

```
fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit
```

and also I then stop receiving any messages from any sender, not just this ip address I want to ban...

any idesas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not block it with iptables or at your firewall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it was written by Weitze Venema, it should be compile against tcp wrappers - just add the ip to [/etc/hosts.deny](http://purebsd.com/tcp-wrappers-hosts-access.html)

For automated response to new probes, have a look at fail2ban

Answer (score 2):

[Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org)

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a look at something like Fail2Ban. It can monitor the log files and block ips based on certain criteria using iptables. This means that Postfix will be left to do what it does best and deliver mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple iptables rule :

iptables -I INPUT -s ip_to_block -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using Fail2Ban, you may be in the same boat I was in: it's hard to find good info on how to permanently ban IP's.  This article was a godsend for me!
[Fail2Ban: Permanent SSH Bans](http://n8wood.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/fail2ban-permanent-ssh-bans/)